# Writing input to a process - RedirectStandardInput not working

Tags: c#, windows, input, process

This has been driving me nuts for all day now. I'm not sure anymore if I'm doing something dumb here, but all the standard solutions and work-arounds I've tried are without any positive result. I'm sorry for asking a question similar to many already existing, but all my queries are greeted by more solutions of the same type like below, pieces of code that sadly do not have any effect in my specific case. Maybe it's something peculiar about the process itself.

**The goal is extremely simple: I have an external process (.exe) that I want to programmatically send input to.**

Redirecting the output goes without any issue: the program starts and I get the expected output in screen. If I focus the process and manually give input (type command and press enter), the program responds as expected as well: it echoes back the command in a specific format. Yet, the automated "Test" statements below are not returned for some reason. They do not show up in the application itself either, so I'm certain that the program does not receive anything at all.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Factorio_AutomatedAdmin
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var workingDir = @"E:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Factorio\bin\x64\";

            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                WorkingDirectory = workingDir,
                FileName = $"{workingDir}factorio",
                Arguments = @"--server-settings server-settings.json --start-server server.zip"""
            };

            var process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = psi,
                EnableRaisingEvents = true
            };

            process.Start();

            process.OutputDataReceived += (o, e) =>
            {
                var err = "";
                if (e.Data == null) err = e.Data;
                else Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
            };
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();

            process.ErrorDataReceived += (o, e) =>
            {
                var err = "";
                if (e.Data == null) err = e.Data;
                else Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
            };

            process.BeginErrorReadLine();

            StreamWriter sw = process.StandardInput;

            while (true)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Test");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

UPDATE:
Still can't get it to work in C#, but the following code for PowerShell does actually have the desired effect:

```
$dir = "E:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Factorio\bin\x64\"
$serverPath = $dir + "factorio.exe"
$spectator = "Tybs"

Set-Location -Path $dir

$psi = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo;
$psi.FileName = $serverPath; #process file
$psi.UseShellExecute = $false; #start the process from it's own executable file
$psi.RedirectStandardInput = $true; #enable the process to read from standard input
$psi.RedirectStandardOutput = $true; #enable the process to read from standard output
$psi.RedirectStandardError = $true;
$psi.Arguments = '--server-settings "E:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Factorio\bin\x64\server-settings.json" --start-server tybsania.zip'

$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $psi

# Register Object Events for stdin\stdout reading
$OutEvent = Register-ObjectEvent -Action {
    $data = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Data
    Write-Host $data
    return $data
} -InputObject $p -EventName OutputDataReceived -MessageData $players

$ErrEvent = Register-ObjectEvent -Action {
    Write-Host $Event.SourceEventArgs.Data
} -InputObject $p -EventName ErrorDataReceived

[void]$p.Start()
$p.BeginOutputReadLine();
$p.BeginErrorReadLine();

while($true)
{
    $cmd = Read-Host "Command"
    $p.StandardInput.WriteLine($cmd)
}
```

It is a workaround at least. Still, if anyone has an answer for C#, I would like to hear it: this would give me more options to work with.

Comment: I tried your sample and it worked for me (but I used my own program to accept redirected input). Lets check if your executable `factorio` accepts input redirected to file (if it cannot I suspect that it also cannot read input redirected to another program). To make it create a file `input.txt`, fill it with text/commands and then run your executable using the next command `factorio {arguments} < input.txt`. Is your executable able to read `STDIN` from file?

Comment: Tried it, but sadly it didn't have any effect.

I just managed to redirect input by using PowerShell though: so apparently it is capable of receiving input, just not using the C# sample above. Still, it would be nice to be able to do this in C#. I'll edit my original past with the powershell code.

Comment: Have you tried to change `C#` version of the program to match `PowerShell` version of the program. I see that there are some differences: 1. `C#` version uses `workingDirectory`, `PowerShell` version does not; 2. `C#` version specifies executable path without `.exe` extension; 3. `C#` specifies encoding and other properties of the `ProcessStartInfo` that are not specified in the `PowerShell` version; 4. and etc. Try to rewrite `C#` version of the program to 100% match `PowerShell` version of the program. May it will help you.

Comment: Already tried, but it had the exact same result as the first version. Still, thanks for the input!

Comment: @Tybs, put the latest version of your C# code with all the changes you have tried since publishing the question. Show please some respect for other people's time. E.g. your C# code in the question still doesn't have the *.exe extension after factorio. Iliar Turdushev was talking about this a couple of days ago.

Comment: @Tybs, try your C# solution with some other exe-file that everyone can find and reproduce the bug with on his\her Windows machine and add to your question the results of your test. If necessary, create some simple program instead of factorio.exe and post its code. Simplify input as much as possible for the test. I think, If other people can reproduce the bug with this exe-file then you may expect some help. I personally have no idea what is factorio.exe